# Occurrence of 5 consecutive tails before occurrence of 2 consecutive heads

Tags: probability

In repeated tossing of a fair coin find the probability that $5$ consecutive tails occur before occurrence of $2$ consecutive heads.

My attempt:
I tried to find the probability of non-occurrence of two consecutive heads in $n$ throws.

Let $a_{n}$ be the number of possibilities in which $2$ consecutive heads do not occur in $n$ throws.

I managed to find the recursion formula.

$a_{1}=2$

$a_{2}=3$

$a_{n}=a_{n-1}+a_{n-2}$

But I am not able to get a closed form of $a_{n}$.

Once $a_{n}$ gets determined it may be possible then to find probability of occurrence of $5$ consecutive heads

Comment: The solutions to your recurrence are basically the Fibonacci seqience, for which there is a closed form that I think will not be helpful.

Comment: Besides, I don't understand the last sentence- You want the probability of 5 consecutive _tails_, and I don't see how $a_n$ would lead you you that.

Comment: @leonbloy Well you're doing better than me, I don't understand even the question. It's a unique nonrepeating 7-bit sequence, so the odds of it starting at any particular coin toss seems obviously 1 in 2^7, or 1 in 128. So the odds of it happening in any sequence of tosses is gonna be the same as rolling a 1 on a 128 sided dice, when rolling it (sequence length - 6) times. The minus six because the last 6 coin-tosses cannot start the sequence. So I don't get what's being asked. But then I'm bad at math.

Answer (score 9):

A different approach: consider two independent geometric vars $X_1$ ,$X_2$, each of which measures the amount of trials until getting a success, in an experiment with prob. of success $p_1$ (resp $p_2)$

Then 
$$P(X_1 \le X_2)=p_1 + p_1 q_1 q_2 +p_1 (q_1 q_2)^2+\cdots=\frac{p_1}{1- q_1 q_2} $$

$$P(X_1 < X_2)=p_1 q_2  + p_1 q_2 q_1 q_2 +p_1 q_2 (q_1 q_2)^2+\cdots=\frac{p_1 q_2}{1- q_1 q_2} $$

We can consider each run of tails/heads such experiments, with $p_1=1/2^{5-1}=2^{-4}$, $p_2 =1/2$

Let $E$ be the desired event (run of 5 tails happens before run of 2 heads). Let $T$ be the event that the first coin is a tail. Then

$$P(E)=P(E|T)P(T)+P(E|T^c)P(T^c)=\\
=\frac{p_1}{1- q_1 q_2} \frac{1}{2}+\frac{p_1 q_2}{1- q_1 q_2} \frac{1}{2}=\\=\frac{1}{2} (1+q_2)\frac{p_1}{1- q_1 q_2} =\frac{3}{34} $$

In general

$$P(E)=\frac{2^h-1}{2^t+2^h-2}$$

Seeing that the final formula is so simple, I wonder if there is a simpler derivation.

Comment: Upvoted (+1) after verification.

Comment: @leonbloy: Instructive answer! (+1)

Comment: why is $p_{1}=\frac{1}{2^{5-1}}$ and not $\frac{1}{2^5}$. Similarly,should not $p_{2}=\frac{1}{2^2}$ instead of $\frac{1}{2}$

Comment: @PankajSinha Each run of head (tails) has by itself a starting head (tail). That should not be counted. For example, (for $p_2$) the probability that a head run is of length at least 2 is $p_2 = 1/2$ (or one minus the probaiblity that the head run has length $1$)

Comment: Can I say that to obtain a run of $5$ tails it is necessary to obtain $4$ tails whose probability is $\frac{1}{2^{-4}}$ and then for a run of $5$ tails to occur one tail may happen before $4$ consecutive tails occur or after these $4$ consecutive tails occur whose probability will be $\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\right)$

Comment: @PankajSinha Sorry, I couldn't parse that.

Comment: @leonbloy it seems odd that the formula is asymmetric, i.e. the order of head/tail as arguments matter (e.g. 5 head, 2 tails vs. 5 tails, 2 heads), considering that in coin toss literature often head/tail are interchangeable (assumption of a fair coin). Your thoughts appreciated.

Comment: @tngn The formula $P_{t,h}$ corresponds to the event: "$t$  cons. tails before $h$ cons. heads". If the formula were symmetric, then the event $A:$ "5 cons tails before 2 cons. heads" would have equal probability than the event  $B:$ "2 cons tails before 5 cons. heads", which is not at all obvious (indeed, it's false). Which is obvious, by symmetry and fair coin, is that $A$ is equivalent to $C:$ "5 cons heads before 2 cons. tails"

Answer (score 2):

This problem can be solved using Markov chains. Unfortunatley, this approach requires a bunch of tiresome matrix manipulations. I won't work through the details for you, but instead outline of solution.

Define the following states 
$0$ : the ground state.
$t_1$: 1 tail has occurred
...
$t_5$: 5 tails have occurred
$h_1$: 1 head has occurred
$h_2$ : 2 heads have occurred.

Here $t_5$ and $h_2$ are your termination states - i.e your game ends when you reach either state. So basically, you need to the expected time of hitting first $t_5$ versus first hitting $h_2$.

Now, write down the transition probability matrix. It will look something like this:
$$Pr[ 0 \rightarrow t_1] = 1/2$$
$$Pr[0 \rightarrow h_1] = 1/2$$
$$Pr[t_i \rightarrow h_1] = 1/2$$
$$Pr[t_i \rightarrow t_{i+1}] = 1/2$$ 
etc.

Next, solve the expectation relationships as follows.

Define $ \tau_{j,k}$ = time to go from state $j$ to state $k$.

then the expected time to go from the ground state to $t_5$ can be composed into the path taken at the first step, either via $t_1$ or $h_1$...
$$ E[ \tau_{0, t_5} ] = 1+E[ \tau_{t_1, t_5} ]1/2 + E[ \tau_{h_1, t_5} ]1/2  $$

similarly the time to go  from the 1-tail state $t_1$ to the final state $t_5$ can be broken down by intermediate paths:
$$E[ \tau_{t_1, t_5} ]=  1+E[\tau_{t_2, t_5} ]1/2 + E[ \tau_{h_1, t_5}]1/2$$
$$E[ \tau_{t_2, t_5} ]=  1+E[\tau_{t_3, t_5} ]1/2 + E[ \tau_{h_1, t_5}]1/2$$
$$E[ \tau_{t_3, t_5} ]=  1+E[\tau_{t_4, t_5} ]1/2 + E[ \tau_{h_1, t_5}]1/2$$
$$E[ \tau_{t_4, t_5} ]=  1/2 + E[ \tau_{h_1, t_5}]1/2$$

and so on an so forth.

As I said, it's quite tedious, but it'll get you the solution as linear system of equations.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a  slightly different proof which may be  of interest although
it is not as elegant as the one by @leonbloy.

Suppose we treat the problem of $t$ tails before $h$ heads.

Encoding this in  a generating function with $u$  marking sequences of
tails of length at  least $t$ and $v$ sequences of  heads of length at
least $h$  and finally $w$ marking  the final occurrence of  $h$ heads
and introducing

$$G_t(z) = z+z^2+\cdots +z^{t-1}+uz^t\frac{1}{1-z}
\quad\text{and}\quad
G_h(z) = z+z^2+\cdots +z^{h-1}+vz^h\frac{1}{1-z}$$

we obtain

$$H(z) = (1+G_t(z))
\left(\sum_{k\ge 0} G_h(z)^k G_t(z)^k\right)
\left(1+z+\cdots+z^{h-1} + wz^h + z^{h+1}\frac{1}{1-z}\right).$$

Observe that when we remove the three markers $u,v$ and $w$ we obtain

$$Q(z) = \frac{1}{1-z} 
\left(\sum_{k\ge 0} \frac{z^k}{(1-z)^k} \frac{z^k}{(1-z)^k}\right)
\frac{1}{1-z}
\\ = \frac{1}{(1-z)^2} \frac{1}{1-z^2/(1-z)^2}
= \frac{1}{(1-z)^2-z^2} = \frac{1}{1-2z}$$

which  is good  news because  it means  we have  enumerated all  $2^n$
possible bit strings of length $n.$

Now extracting  coefficients we  are interested in  the series  on $w$
which yields

$$H_1(z) = z^h (1+G_t(z))
\left(\sum_{k\ge 0} G_h(z)^k G_t(z)^k\right)$$

The next step is to discard those terms that have $v\ge 1$ (meaning an
internal occurrence of $h$ heads) which yields on setting $v=0$

$$H_2(z) = z^h (1+G_t(z))
\left(\sum_{k\ge 0} 
\left(z\frac{1-z^{h-1}}{1-z}\right)^k G_t(z)^k\right).$$

Finally we need to compute
$$H_3(z) = 
\left. H_2(z)\right|_{u=1} - \left. H_2(z)\right|_{u=0}$$

to remove those terms not containing a run of at least $t$ tails.

This yields

$$H_3(z) = z^h \frac{1}{1-z}
\left(\sum_{k\ge 0} 
\left(z\frac{1-z^{h-1}}{1-z}\right)^k 
\left(\frac{z}{1-z}\right)^k\right)
\\ - z^h \frac{1-z^t}{1-z}
\left(\sum_{k\ge 0} 
\left(z\frac{1-z^{h-1}}{1-z}\right)^k 
\left(z\frac{1-z^{t-1}}{1-z}\right)^k\right).$$

This finally produces

$$H_3(z) = z^h\frac{1}{1-z}
\frac{1}{1-z^2 (1-z^{h-1})/(1-z)^2}
\\ - z^h\frac{1-z^t}{1-z}
\frac{1}{1- z^2(1-z^{h-1})(1-z^{t-1}))/(1-z)^2}
\\ = z^h
\frac{1-z}{(1-z)^2-z^2 (1-z^{h-1})}
\\ - z^h (1-z^t)
\frac{1-z}{(1-z)^2- z^2 (1-z^{h-1})(1-z^{t-1})}
\\ = z^h
\frac{1-z}{1 - 2z + z^{h+1}}
- z^h (1-z^t)
\frac{1-z}{1 - 2z + z^{h+1} + z^{t+1} - z^{h+t}}.$$

We obtain the probability by setting $z=1/2$
which yields

$$\frac{1}{2^{h+1}} 2^{h+1} 
- \frac{1}{2^{h+1}} \left(1-\frac{1}{2^t}\right)
\frac{1}{1/2^{h+1}+1/2^{t+1}-1/2^{h+t}}
\\ = 1
- \frac{2^t-1}{2^{h+t+1}}
\frac{1}{1/2^{h+1}+1/2^{t+1}-1/2^{h+t}}
\\ = 1
- (2^t-1)
\frac{1}{2^t+2^h-2}
= \frac{2^t+2^h-2-(2^t-1)}{2^t+2^h-2}
\\ = \frac{2^h-1}{2^t+2^h-2}.$$

Comment: Nice approach! (+1)

Answer (score 1):

There is an intuitive way to think about this.

Let $E$ be the probability of success. Let $\mathbb{T}$ denote the probability of success starting with a `T` first; Let $\mathbb{H}$ denote the probability of success starting with an `H` first.

To illustrate, the event space can be partitioned into $\mathbb{T}$ and $\mathbb{H}$:

\begin{align}
\mathbb{H}&: &H \\
\mathbb{T}&: &TH \\
& &TTH \\
& &TTTH \\
& &TTTTH \\
& &TTTTT
\end{align}

If we get `H` on the first flip, to succeed requires getting a `T` next. If we get `T` on the first flip, the series of outcomes listed above under $\mathbb{T}$ can lead to success. With these, we can derive the following equations.
$$
P(E|\mathbb{H}) = \frac{1}{2}P(E|\mathbb{T}) \\
P(E|\mathbb{T}) = \left ( \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{8} + \frac{1}{16} \right )  P(E|\mathbb{H}) + \frac{1}{16}
$$

Finally, $P(E) = \frac{1}{2} P(E|\mathbb{H}) +  \frac{1}{2} P(E|\mathbb{T}) = \frac{3}{34}$.

In general,
$$
P(E|\mathbb{H}) = \left( 1 - \frac{1}{2^{h-1}} \right) P(E|\mathbb{T}) \\
P(E|\mathbb{T}) = \left( 1 - \frac{1}{2^{t-1}} \right) P(E|\mathbb{H}) + \frac{1}{2^{t-1}}
$$

Solving them gives
$$
P(E) = \frac{2^h - 1}{2^h + 2^t - 2}
$$